# Java 8 Hijrah Date Error when Day of Month is 30

Tags: java

I have been getting an error when using Hijrah date

the error is:

```
Invalid Hijrah day of month: 30
```

the code is:

```
String date = 13820630;
        HijrahDate hDate= HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(Integer.valueOf(date.substring(0, 4)),Integer.valueOf(date.substring(4, 6)), Integer.valueOf(date.substring(6, 8)));
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The comments for `HijrahChronology` say "The Hijrah calendar has several variants based on differences in when the new moon is determined to have occurred and where the observation is made." -- presumably the logic in the class has determined that that particular month in that year has only 29 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `HijrahDate` class, the month 1372-06 has only 29 days.

```
HijrahDate date = HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(1382, 6, 1);
System.out.println(date.lengthOfMonth());
```

This code prints 29.

The comments for [`HijrahChronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/HijrahChronology.html) say

> The Hijrah calendar has several variants based on differences in when the new moon is determined to have occurred and where the observation is made. In some variants the length of each month is computed algorithmically from the astronomical data for the moon and earth and in others the length of the month is determined by an authorized sighting of the new moon. For the algorithmically based calendars the calendar can project into the future. For sighting based calendars only historical data from past sightings is available.

So it is possible that the variant used by this chronology may differ from what you are expecting.

Other variants may be available via [`Chronology.getAvailableChronologies()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/Chronology.html#getAvailableChronologies--)

Comment: By default, Hijrah chronology uses "Hijrah Umm al-Qura" calendar, and here is [the properties file](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/lib/hijrah-config-umalqura.properties) which seems to guide how that particular chronology works. As you can see, month "06 of 1382" only has 29 days in that properties file (not to be thorny, just adding what came from where).